# Difference between OR and AND?

Tags: boolean-logic

I am creating an expression for a WQL query, in order to target a Software Deployment at machines which have neither Version1 or Version2 of the software.

I have come up with two expressions that both seem to have the same outcome and wanted to run this logic against you to see if these expressions are truly equivalent? If so, I will probably go for Expression 1.

> **Expression 1:**
>
> Deploy Software.version1 to Machine IF Machine IS in "Group1" AND
>   Machine IS NOT Software.version1 AND Machine IS NOT Software.version2
>
> **Expression 2:**
>
> Deploy Software.version1 to Machine IF Machine IS in "Group1" AND (
>   Machine IS NOT Software.version1 OR Machine IS NOT Software.version2 )

My brain is starting to hurt.

Many Thanks

Comment: neither Version1 **nor** Version2. think about it.

Answer (score 2):

In Expression 1, all three conditions have to be true (machine in group 1 and not version 1 and not version 2). In Expression 2, two conditions must be true: either machine is in group 1 and not version 1 or machine is group 1 and not version 2.

Assuming that the machine can't have both version 1 and version 2 at the same time, the second expression will always be true if the machine is in group 1. The first expression will only be true if the machine is in group 1 and has neither version 1 nor version 2.

In logical terms, you have:

```
exp1 = g1 ∧ ~v1 ∧ ~v2

exp2 = g1 ∧ (~v1 ∨ ~v2)
     = g1 ∧ ~(v1 ∧ v2)   // by DeMorgan's theorem
```

So the answer is **no, the two expressions are not equivalent**. If you don't see why, write out the truth table for all three conditions and both expressions.

Comment: Yes. It is fair to assume that a machine will not have both Software versions.

Comment: Software package needs to be deployed to machines which don't already have the package (version1) nor a later version of the package (version2). In effect, it really only should deploy if you have neither. When I run through the logic, both expressions give me the result I want....I think....That is that there is no risk of deploying Software Version1 to machines that already have Version1 or Version2?

Comment: Read what I wrote again. Using your second expression, the package will be deployed to every group 1 machine that doesn't have *both* version 1 *and* version 2. If only one version can be installed at a time, then you'll *always* deploy the package to a group 1 machine. If a machine has version 1, then it doesn't have version 2, so `~v2` is true, which means `(~v1 ∨ ~v2)` is true. For the same reason, if a machine has version 2, `(~v1 ∨ ~v2)` will again be true. The first expression, however, works as you describe: you'll deploy *only* to those machines that have neither v1 nor v2.

Comment: I think the penny is dropping. Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the langue, but the logic seems pretty straight forward.

If I understand the question correctly, you want:

- (1,1) -> 1 (is neither version 1 nor 2)
- (1,0) -> 0 (is version 2)
- (0,1) -> 0 (is version 1)
- (0,0) -> 0 (is version 1 and 2)

This will be achieved by Expression 1.

Expression 2 will return:

- (1,1) -> 1
- (1,0) -> 1
- (0,1) -> 1
- (0,0) -> 0

I strongly recommend you to test with whatever the langue will help you with (I'm sure there is some kind of print bool-function), and because it isn't much to test, really, just test all the three or four possibilites and see if it returns what you want.